# Python Pony ORM record update exception

Tags: python-2.7, orm, ponyorm

In the Python ORM [Pony](https://ponyorm.com/), If I try to insert a record but it already exists, I would like to try updating the record instead.

I receive the following error when the record already exists:
`pony.orm.core.TransactionIntegrityError: Object Record[1234] cannot be stored in the database. IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: Record.id`

**EDIT**: However, it seems this error is re-thrown even when I am trying to update the record. Here's my highly simplified example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

from pony.orm import *

db = Database()

class Record(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int)

db.bind("sqlite", "database.sqlite", create_db=True)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

records = [{"id":1234},{"id":1234}]

@db_session
def saveRecords(records):
    for r in records:
        try:
            Record(**r)
        except Exception as e:
            print("error caught")
            p = Record.get(id=r.get("id"))
            p.set(**r)

saveRecords(records)
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

### This works for me

```
sql_debug(True)
records = [{"id":1233},{"id":1236}]

def saveRecords(records):
    with db_session:
        for r in records:
            try:
                print "inserting"
                print r
                Record(**r)
                commit()
            except Exception as e:
                print("error caught")
                print e 
            #p = Record.get(id=r.get("id"))
            #p.set(**r)

saveRecords(records)
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I think this is less about catching the first error and more about what to do about the error once caught. When you comment out the lines `p = Record.get(id=r.get("id"))` and `p.set(**r)` the record isn't updated.